# What is the probability of obtaining exactly 2 Cs and 1 A in four tests?

Tags: probability

In a test, the chance to get A is $0.08$, the chance to get B is $0.02$, and the chance to get C is $0.9$ We do 4 tests. The question is what is the probability that we get exactly 2 Cs and 1 A?

I said that I multiply $p(c) \cdot p(c) \cdot p(a)$, and since there are $4$ tests and no importance for order I multiply by $4!$. I'm not sure if this is correct, and should I divide by 2! too since we want 2 C? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does you need exactly 2 Cs and 1 A, or at least 2 Cs and 1 A?

Comment: Exactly 2 Cs and 1 A

Answer (score 3):

The probability of a specific order of two $C$, one $A$ and one $B$ is $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)^2$. The number of total orders is ${4 \choose 2}2!$ as you need to choose which tests will be $C$ (2 out of the 4, without order matters) and then find a place for $A$ (2 options).

**Edit**
Following clarification in the comments, the requirement is in fact "at least 2 $C$ and 1 $A$". In that case, following the same logic, we need to go over all the options: 2A0B2C, 1A1B2C, 1A0B3C:

${4 \choose 2}\Pr(A)^2\Pr(C)^2 + {4 \choose 2}2!\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)^2 + {4 \choose 3}\Pr(A)\Pr(C)^3$

Comment: I don't need to get 1 B.
i do 4 tests, and need 2 Cs and 1 A

Comment: Well, if you need exactly 2 C and 1 A, you must also get a B...

Comment: the 4th one can be whatever, it doesn't matter. for example 3 Cs and 1 A, or 2 Cs 2 As..

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help, really appreciated.
I have another little question, if I need 4 Cs, do i do (0.09)^4 then divide by 4! ?

Comment: No need to divide, as there is only one order. The reason you have all these factors (here and in other answers) is that CCAB and CABC should be counted twice. However, for 4C you have only CCCC.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of obtaining one A, one B, and two Cs in that order is $(0.08)(0.02)(0.9)^2$.  The number of orders in which one A, one B, and two Cs can be obtained is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$ since we must choose one of the positions for the A, one of the remaining three positions for the B, and then fill both of the remaining two positions with Cs.  Hence, the probability of obtaining one A, one B, and two Cs is
$$\binom{4}{1, 1, 2}(0.08)^1(0.02)^1(0.9)^2 = \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}(0.08)^1(0.02)^1(0.9)^2$$
The number
$$\binom{4}{1, 1, 2} = \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{4!}{1!3!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{2!0!} = \frac{4!}{1!1!2!}$$
is called a *multinomial coefficient*.  See this page on the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I have another little question, if I need 4 Cs, do i do (0.09)^4 then divide by 4! ?

Comment: If there are 4 Cs, you would have $\binom{4}{0, 0, 4}(0.9)^4 = \frac{4!}{0!0!4!}(0.9)^4 = (0.9)^4$.

Comment: After rereading the question, I noticed that the probability of obtaining a C was $0.9$ for each trial, so I have corrected my calculations.